# Contractsccrwrite.rsp exited with code 1 ERROR

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-contracts

I have met with frustrating problem when running my console application.
I was trying to code my program with Code contracts.Let me make you know I have installed the Add-on for code contracts and I am using Vs2013.
When running the program I get the following Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File Line Error
>
> The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrewrite.exe" "@Type
> Validation and Contractsccrewrite.rsp"" exited with code 1.Type
> Validation and Contracts

I have surfed through the internet a lot and modify the changes,still the error does not leave me.
I have used Contracts.Requires statement at the beginning of the method.
I like to share the changes that I have made on the project properties [image]

And also I had set Contract reference Assembly menu to 'none'.If i had changed it to 'Build'.The i get another error replacing the above

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error
>
> The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrefgen.exe"
> "@obj\Debug\Type Validation and Contractsccrefgen.rsp"" exited with
> code 1.   Type Validation and Contracts